# Error 500 with authorization while consuming OAuth2 RESTful service through C#

Tags: c#, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication

My current job is to consume a RESTful API with OAuth2. Currently I worked out how to get the access token and it is working ok while I use the chrome extension Rest Console, but when I try to do it from my application I always get the error that I am sending an invalid OAuth request. Below you can see three of the ways I tried to consume the API, but to no success. The page always returns error 500. Any help will be appreciated, if I had missed something crucial.

```
    var auth = "Bearer " + item.access_token;


    /* First Attempt */
    var client = new RestClient("http://<link>");
    var request = new RestRequest("sample", Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", auth);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    request.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36");
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    var response = client.Execute(request);
    var content = response.Content;





    /* Second Attempt */
    string sURL = "http://<link>/sample";

    string result = "";

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers["Authorization"] = auth;
        client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
        client.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
        client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36";
        client.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters);

        var result1 = client.DownloadString(sURL);
    }


    /* Third Attempt */
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.Headers["Authorization"] = auth;
    request.UserAgent = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36";
    string content;
    HttpStatusCode statusCode;
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        var contentType = response.ContentType;
        Encoding encoding = null;
        if (contentType != null)
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(contentType, @"(?<=charset\=).*");
            if (match.Success)
                encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(match.ToString());
        }

        encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;

        statusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding))
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

--------EDIT--------

For the first attempt I also tried to add the authentication to the client variable `client.Authenticator = Authenticate;` where `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator Authenticate = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(item.access_token, item.token_type);`

Comment: Should you really be using `var auth = "Bearer " + item.access_token;` instead of your client's identifier and secret for the token retrieval? Where did the access_token come from if you can only manage to get the authorization code? You could also try to leave out your "Pragma", "User-Agent" and "Accept" headers, they might not be necessary here.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking 'References' in your solution explorer and using 'Add Service Reference'?  It may be a big help and reduce your coding time.

Comment: item.accesss_token is gotten earlier addressing another part of the same API using the Second Attempt written in my code. It's parsed correctly and if I use the token I got from this with Rest Console the api works as expected. I tried without the additional headers, but didn't make any difference. I read somewhere that I can pass the access_token through the url so I tried that - didn't work.

Comment: Which API are you trying to access exactly? It'd be uncommon to use a token to get a token. You would either trade an authorization code or a refresh token for a new access token. Can you describe the workflow you're using?

Comment: I am sorry for misinterpreting. The second way with the WebClient, I managed to send the request successfully to the API, what you see up there is actually me trying to use the same way to reach the data from the API. The API is not one of the popular ones

Comment: Could you please share a fiddler trace? Please compare the one you get with chrome extension and the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code seems right. The fail attempts you did suggest that the issue is with the token and not the code. Bearer tokens have expiration time. So semms like your token expired between the first time you got it using chrome REST Console extension and when you wrote your code. But the strange situation here is the 500 error code you got. 401 is standard response when you token expired or not exist. 500 error code always mean server error.

Comment: Thank you, for the quick response, but the token is not the problem. The two operations are made one after another. I just got the token and try to request the data from the API, also if I use the same token I used with this request in RestConsole (Chrome extension) it pulls the data correctly. Also I captured the 2 requests with Wireshark, but I couldn't see any differences, so I think there might be something wrong with my code.